# Creating function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create the following procedure in Aginity workbench with DBMS PostgreSQL 8.0.2

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Step1_data_main
( 
@startdate NVARCHAR(MAX),
@enddate NVARCHAR(MAX),
@season NVARCHAR(MAX)
) AS

SELECT level1_idnt,day_dt, sum(sls_qty) as sum_units,sum(sls_amnt_price) as sum_sales
FROM md1.loc_sku_dy_act_pos_full_v2 
WHERE seasn_cd = '+@season+' and day_dt >= ''+@startdate+'' and day_dt <= ''+@enddate+''
GROUP_BY level1_idnt, day_dt;

END


EXEC Step1_data_main
'2015-03-01 00:00:00',
'2015-09-30 00:00:00',
'2'
GO
```

However I am getting the following error

```
syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"
```

Any guidance on this will be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

I am working in Aginity Workbench with PostgreSQL I had previously incorrectly said I am using mysql workbench.

Comment: I do not understand you apostrophes. Are they  correct ?

Comment: Aginity Workbench is something completely different then SQL Workbench/J

Comment: Ok. Any Idea how this problem can be solved in Aginity workbench?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The `syntax error at or near "PROCEDURE"` indicates that your SQL syntax is completely wrong. According to http://www.aginity.com/workbench/ Aginity does not work with MySQL

Comment: The syntax is **completely** wrong for Postgres. There is no `create procedure` in Postgres. Where in the manual did you find that? There is also no `exec` in Postgres. And `GO` is also invalid. And why are you using a totally outdated, ancient and unsupported Postgres version?

Comment: See here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-createfunction.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/plpgsql.html for details on how to create functions in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You should try in this way, Yo are using sql server syntax in mysql thats why getting error.

**This is for MySQL**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Step1_data_main( 
startdate NVARCHAR(20),
enddate NVARCHAR(20),
season NVARCHAR(20))

BEGIN
  SELECT level1_idnt,day_dt, sum(sls_qty) as sum_units,sum(sls_amnt_price) as sum_sales 
     FROM md1.loc_sku_dy_act_pos_full_v2 
       WHERE seasn_cd = '+@season+' and day_dt >= ''+@startdate+'' 
       and day_dt <= ''+@enddate+''
       GROUP BY level1_idnt, day_dt;
END$$
```

**Update1:** This is for SQL Server

```
Create  PROCEDURE Step1_data_main(    
@startdate NVARCHAR(20),                      
@enddate NVARCHAR(20),
@season NVARCHAR(20)        
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT level1_idnt,day_dt, sum(sls_qty) as sum_units,sum(sls_amnt_price) as sum_sales 
     FROM md1.loc_sku_dy_act_pos_full_v2 
       WHERE seasn_cd = '+@season+' and day_dt >= ''+@startdate+'' 
       and day_dt <= ''+@enddate+''
       GROUP BY level1_idnt, day_dt;
END;
```

Comment: I tried in my system it is working fine for me, first you should try this query in mysql workbench......whats error you are getting?

Comment: I think I was incorrect in assuming aginity work bench utilizes mysql. It seems from the documentation it uses sql-workbench/J. Is this why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Step1_data_main`( 
 startdate NVARCHAR(1000),
 enddate NVARCHAR(1000),
 season NVARCHAR(1000)
)
begin

SELECT level1_idnt,day_dt, sum(sls_qty) as sum_units,sum(sls_amnt_price) as sum_sales
FROM md1.loc_sku_dy_act_pos_full_v2 
WHERE seasn_cd = cast(season as UNSIGNED) and 
      day_dt >=  cast(startdate as datetime) and 
      day_dt <=  cast(enddate as datetime)
GROUP BY level1_idnt, day_dt;

END$$
```

Comment: if you doing it via add procedure - remove both DELIMITER from code – Pavel Zimogorov